# Linq - GroupBy and Sum of resulting collection's property

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a collection objects of type `ObjectClass`. I need a query that will return a grouped list of the objects by the `Name`property. For each grouped elements, the respective `Value`property should hold the sum of all the elements' `Value`values in that group - otherwise `Value`should hold the respective `Value`value for unique individual elements. The `ObjectClass` type is shown below.

```
public class ObjectClass 
{
  int Id;
  string Name;
  int Value;
}
```

Let the var `list` be of type `List<ObjectClass>` and an assumption that it contains items in it.

I have tried:

```
   var plas = list.GroupBy(p => p.Name).Select(g => new objectClass{
        Value = g.sum(p.value),
        Name = g.select(a=>a.Name).FirstOrDefault()
        });
```

Kindly point me to the right direction.

Comment: That is not valid C# code.

Comment: It's not clear what _" where int value is the sum of groupbyobject"_ means. Also, you can't ask us if your code works correctly. How could we know better than you?

Comment: The only way we could assess if the code is correct is for you to show us input & output - if the output is not what you want, then I guess you could work out that the code wasn't correct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
int i = 0;
List<ObjectClass> foo = new List<ObjectClass>();

foreach(var item in foo.Where(item => item.Name = filter))
{
  i += item.Value;
}
```

Old but gold

Comment: From what I understand, the OP wants a list returning where each entry in the list consists of the Name from the original list and the sum of all entries in the list with match name - ie a Group By Name query. Your code just filters on a single name & returns a single sum of the values - not what is asked for.

Comment: Thanks! Finally I use it. Linq query is not so efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need... Although I suggest to word the question in a clearer way and to provide input and desired/expected output.

```
void Main()
{
    var someObjects = new List<ObjectClass>();

    someObjects.Add(new ObjectClass(){Name="numberWang", Value = 2});
    someObjects.Add(new ObjectClass(){Name="numberWang", Value = 3});
    someObjects.Add(new ObjectClass(){Name="numberTwang", Value = 4});
    someObjects.Add(new ObjectClass(){Name="numberTwang", Value = 5});

    //You could filter this beforehand with a Where clause ie. someObjects.Where(i=>i.Name == "whatever").Sum(i=>i.Value)
    int sumOfValuesOfAllObjects = someObjects.Sum(i=>i.Value);

    var sumByObjectClassName = someObjects.GroupBy(a=>a.Name).Select(b=>
    new ObjectClass() { Name = b.First().Name, Value =b.Sum(c=>c.Value) } );
}   

public class ObjectClass
{
  public string Name;
  public int Value;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need the ToList() in the middle of the Linq, moving it to the end would convert the result to a List though which appears to be what the OP wants.

Comment: Yes, this solution work, but what about performance?

Comment: @PaulF you are right... I left that from another snippet I had in LINQPad... Removed it now and + your comment :)

Comment: @AndreaMerlin - what do you mean about performance? that is a very open question... What's the issue? Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @AndreaMerlin: You will need to try it & see - if it is too slow then you may find that rewriting the Linq in C# code will give better performance.